# Why doesn't xhost +localhost work any longer to run an X application as root?

Tags: x

Debian 9.9.

I want to run an application as root, locally.

In the old days, I could simply as the regular user issue:

```
xhost +localhost
```

Then switch back to root, run the application, and it would work. This doesn't seem to work any longer.

Why not?

Yes, there are other ways to do this, such as at ones outlined here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Running_GUI_applications_as_root

However, I'm simply curious why the old method stopped working. What has changed, and why?

Comment: Are you using X, or Wayland?

Comment: I'm using X on Debian 9.9.

Comment: It's common these days for local X servers to be launched with an argument that tells them not to even listen for TCP connections, `X ... -nolisten tcp ...`.  In that case, using `xhost` to tell the server that TCP connections from `localhost` can be trusted doesn't achieve anything because the connection can not be established.